# jquery height() returning 0 value

Tags: jquery, css

I have a small script written to center the content of a div by setting the padding top & bottom from the adjacent div:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.index-block:first').css({
        'padding-top': (($(window).height() - $('.cta').height()) / 4) - $('footer').height()  + "px",
        'padding-bottom': (($(window).height() - $('.cta').height()) / 4) - $('footer').height()  + "px"
    });
    $('.search').css({
        'padding-top': ($('.brand').height() - $('.search').height()) / 4 + "px",
        'padding-bottom': ($('.brand').height() - $('.search').height()) / 4 + "px"
    });
    alert('brand: ' + $('.brand').height() + ' | search: ' + $('.search').height());
});
```

html:

```
<div class="index-block cta row">
    <div class="col-md-4 brand">
        <img src="/static/images/logo.png" alt="<!-- TMPL_VAR instance_name -->" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 search">
        <h1>Property Experts<br><small>Neighborhood Enthusiasts</small></h1>
        <hr>
        <search-form></search-form>
        <div class="button-group">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/leads/buy"><span>Buying a home?</span></a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/leads/sell"><span>Selling a home?</span></a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/leads/cma"><span>What's my home worth?</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it works fine in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aybca19/5/) but not in my [live demo](http://sandbox.dev.activemls.com/). In the live demo the heights for brand and search are 0;

Comment: The height of the container `div` will be zero until the image is loaded.

Comment: Your fiddle runs onload and your live does not

Comment: yea i changed my code to window load instead of document ready and it works fine. except that you will see the div jump on a slow conntection while it waits for the images to load.

Answer (score 0):

in site move script from `$(window).load(function() {` to `$(document).ready(function() {`